# уменьшение времени получения координат от сенсора или от onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

Определил примерно прямую линию на экране на 10 сантиметров. начинаю вести медленно пальцем и метод onTouchEvent получает координаты и я через принт вывожу их на экран и считаю их количество. допустим получилось 100 координат. начинаю двигать чуть быстрее , пока все те же 100 координат. Дальше по мере ускорения движения пальца, координат становится все меньше и меньше. выходит координаты либо с сенсора либо методом onTouchEvent считываются через определенный промежуток времени. Вопрос: можно ли этот промежуток времени уменьшить.Чтобы получать больше координат.